# How to get product advertising data via SP-API or PA-API?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I have an Amazon seller account and have been selling on Amazon for a while.
Because I need to get the information of products, orders, inventory, ads, etc. more easily, I registered my account on AWS and got OAuth2 credentials and refresh token in seller center, then I can get the information of orders, inventory, payments, etc. through SP-API, but I can't find any way to get the ad data of each SKU or ASIN through SP-API.

By searching, I learned about PA-API, then I logged in with my Amazon seller information at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com and got the Associate ID, then I went to Tools->Product Advertising API->Request access to PA API, and then I see these messages

```
To request for access to PA API you must:

❌ Have completed 3 qualifying sales in 180 days.
❌ Have an approved associate account.
❌ Comply with the associates program Operating Agreement.
```

As I mentioned at the beginning, I have an Amazon seller account and have been selling on Amazon for a while. Why does it tell me this information? What about these 3 sentences mean?
Do I need PA-API to get the ads data of my products on Amazon?

I also try to use this [API](https://github.com/nager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) with Access Key and Secret Key of AWS account and Associate ID, but I got this error in return.

"The Access Key Id xxxxx is not enabled for accessing Product Advertising API. Please sign up for Product Advertising API at [https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/assoc_credentials/home."](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/assoc_credentials/home.%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product Advertising API is for affiliates, you need a different set of credentials for the Amazon ADs API: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/info/api-overview

All your other questions are moot since you're looking at a different API, I know they're named confusingly.